# Sumar y luego sacar el Maximo

Tags: sql-server

tengo un problema con un ejercicio que me dejaron en la uni, y el objetivo es sumar la cantidad de pasajeros que recibe un aereopuerto, cuando corro este codigo me sale 2 en vez de 1, ya que yo quiero el máximo.

```
SELECT S.NOMBRE,S.PASAJEROS
FROM (
    SELECT AE.NOMBRE, SUM(AV.PASAJEROS) PASAJEROS
    FROM VUELO VUE
    JOIN
    AVION AV ON AV.IDAVION = VUE.IDAVION
    JOIN
    AEROPUERTO AE ON AE.IDAERO = VUE.IDAERO
    GROUP BY AE.NOMBRE
) S
WHERE S.PASAJEROS = (
    SELECT MAX(AV1.PASAJEROS)
    FROM VUELO VUE1
    JOIN
    AVION AV1 ON VUE1.IDAVION = AV1.IDAVION
    JOIN
    AEROPUERTO AE1 ON VUE1.IDAERO = AE1.IDAERO
    WHERE AE1.NOMBRE = S.NOMBRE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes una consulta que devuelve una suma, conviértela en sub consulta y extrae de ahí el valor máximo:

```
SELECT nombre,
       Max(pasajeros) PASAJEROS
FROM   (SELECT AE.nombre,
               Sum(AV.pasajeros) PASAJEROS
        FROM   vuelo VUE
               JOIN avion AV
                 ON AV.idavion = VUE.idavion
               JOIN aeropuerto AE
                 ON AE.idaero = VUE.idaero
        GROUP  BY AE.nombre)T
```